# Releasing images not created with init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi every one I have the next issue I'm creating various images like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageName];
```

and I'm assigning to one UIImageView

```
[self.imgvImage setImage:image];
```

The user when tap a button one UIImageView is created and one UIImage is assigning, I have 4 UIImageViews created when new is created the last is removed sending release to the UIImageView like this

```
[_imgvImage release];
```

But around than 100 times creating and releasing one memory warring happen but the app dont crash I think this is because the UIImages created are not releasing and there are so much because all the code are clean and creating and releasing are all fine.

How can I remove all the UIIMageView with his UIImage completely from the memory.

Please help, sorry for my English in not good.

Answer (score 1):

The image created using below statement is handled by iOS. this image is stored in a cache so that next time you call this it is simply get returned from the cache.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageName];
```

I think you should not worry about memory warning as long as you are releasing what you are allocating (UIImageView in this case). iOS should clear this cache in case of memory crunch.

If you do not want that caching (e.g. when you are loading one image once only) you can use imageWithContentsOfFile: method of UIImage.

Comment: Thanks @MSK exactly I dont want to caching this images I'm gona try with imageWithContentsOfFile, and I'll be telling you!

Comment: Your'e answer are good but not to me because I have one class what found the image if not exist downloaded it from internet but when the image is founded the image is seted in the class who I make the request and the image given is one image autoreleased for not memory leaks thanks anyway.

Comment: @NTTake In addition to my other comment about showing us the property/ivar declarations and the code to create the image views, you might want to show us this code, too.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I found the solution the solution was call the

```
NSAutoreleasePool
```

in the method when I removed the objects of the view like this:

```
for(ProductVW *pVW in [_vwProductsContainer subviews]){

            NSAutoreleasePool * autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            [pVW removeFromSuperview];

            [autoreleasePool release];

}
```

Comment: This is _not_ a good solution. Your problem undoubtedly rests in how you create your imageviews (I hope they are created with `autorelease` or explicitly issue a `release` immediately after adding them to your view) and how your `@property` is declared for the imageviews. If you share your variable declarations and the code you use to create and remove the imageviews, the solution will be easy. But we can't advise without a more complete code sample.

Comment: Hi @RobertRyan thanks for the response but I dont now why I have a class (FindImage.h/.m) who give me the UIImage, in other class like (Product.h/m) when I create one Product  I make a request of the image in FindImage and the request give me one UIIMage like this  `UIImage *image = nil; image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]; [_delegate FindImageFoundImage:image];` and in the Product when the image is received is seted to the UIImageView like this `UIImageView *imgVW = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; self.imgvProduct  = imgVW;
[imgVW release]; [self addSubview:_imgvProduct];`help

Comment: Seriously, if you want help, **post your code** (and more than the few lines above; post _everything_ that affects retain counts). And do it by updating your question (where the code is legible) rather than in comments (where it isn't). This is painful trying to diagnose the problem on the basis of one or two snippets in comments. A couple of immediate reactions, though: 1. I don't understand what `FindImageFoundImage` does if image is not found. 2. How is imgvProduct is declared? (If retain/copy, are you setting it to nil later? Are you sure you're not accidentally using the ivar later? Etc.)